# Wordpress install in subdirectory is giving 404s

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I've installed a clean version of Wordpress, PHP, and Apache on an EC2 instance. My document root is `/var/www` and Wordpress is un-tarred in `/var/www/wordpress`. If I get http://www.example.com/wordpress, I get:

```
$ wget https://www.example.com/wordpress/
--2018-03-10 18:05:21--  https://www.example.com/wordpress/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... IP, IP
Connecting to www.example.com 
(www.example.com)|IP|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-10 18:05:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

However, if I comment out the existing code in index.php and put in `echo('foo');`, I get:

```
$ curl https://www.example.com/wordpress/
foo
```

So obviously it's loading index.php fine, I'd guess it can't find some file "deeper" in the Wordpress include stack?  But I don't see anything in the error nor access logs about it:

```
172.31.81.199 - - [10/Mar/2018:18:04:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 177 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.42.132 - - [10/Mar/2018:18:05:06 +0000] "GET /blog/feed/atom/ HTTP/1.1" 404 293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.432 Safari/537.36"
172.31.81.199 - - [10/Mar/2018:18:05:21 +0000] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Wget/1.18 (linux-gnu)"
172.31.42.132 - - [10/Mar/2018:18:05:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 177 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: I think you have to change  from option page (home and site page url)  as per the example url. Then reset the permalink.

Comment: I can’t load the option page.